# Как найти диаметр и связность графа?

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Есть некий граф, нужно найти его диаметр и связность. подскажите алгоритм правильный для этой задачи. спасибо заранее) граф задан геометрическим способом

Допустим есть граф из 5 вершин, и его ребра:

```
((0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)
 (1,0)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)
 (2,0)(2,1)(2,3)(2,4)(2,4)
 (3,0)(3,1)(3,2)(3,4)(3,5)
 (4,0)(4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,5)
 (5,0)(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4))
```

вот и нужно найти связность и диаметр для него

Comment: А вы вообще пробовали использовать Google? Для нахождения каждого из этих параметров существует масса годных алгоритмов. В чем, собственно, вопрос-то?

Comment: (1) это вопрос скорее по математике (2) а что вы называете «геометрическим способом»? (3) какую из миллиона разновидностей графа вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Если вы перечислите точные условия, то это будет интересная алгоритмическая задача. А в общем виде ответ будет размером с книгу.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin поправил шапку

Comment: Эээ... А длина рёбер считается равной 1? А граф считается ориентированным?

Answer (score 3):

В вашем конкретном случае это полный граф, он связный и его диаметр равен единице (как у любого полного графа).

Вообще связность неориентированного графа легко определяется обычным [алгоритмом Дейкстры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B) — поиском в ширину (или в глубину) от произвольной вершины. Если удалось посетить все вершины, значит, граф связный. Если нужно найти количество областей связности, то начните поиск повторно с произвольной непосещённой вершины, и так далее, пока не посетите все. Сколько раз потребовалось искать, столько и областей связности.

Для нахождения диаметра графа (максимального расстояния между парами вершин), надо найти все кратчайшие пути между каждой парой вершин. Например, [алгоритмом Флойда-Уоршелла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0) (считая веса рёбер единичными). Это сработает и для ориентированного графа.